# What does transparent mean in "a transparent network file system"?

Tags: operating-system

I was reading a research paper and it says "a transparent network file system". And I recall that I saw "transparent" several times but has not fully understood what it means. Anybody could explain what does it mean in "a transparent network file system"?

Comment: Can you quote complete sentence? Provide the context, link the "a research paper"? When was it published (terminology is changing)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual term is "network-transparent filesystem", a filesystem that's network-transparent (not a network filesystem that's transparent).

An application is *network-transparent* when it is able to work across the network, without the user being aware that there's a network in the way.  For example, the X Window System is network-transparent: a user of X is (in principle) able to run applications across the network without the user being aware that they are not local.

A network-transparent filesystem is therefore a filesystem that (in-principle) gives access to remote files as though they were local.

Comment: That is what I am confused about. Doesn't "without the user being aware that there's a network in the way" mean NOT transparent instead of transparent in English?

Comment: The user doesn't see the network — so the network is transparent to the user.